# MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While debugging ASP.NET MVC source i found **"MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml"** file is used.
But i am not able to understand the use of this file.I mean where is this file stored?
How asp.net MVc makes use of this file?
Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file is used to cache controller types to avoid expensive reflection lookups. It is dynamically generated and stored in the `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\NAMEOFYOURAPP\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\UserCache\` folder.

It's handled by the `TypeCacheUtil` internal class that you could find in the TypeCacheUtil.cs in the ASP.NET MVC source code.

Here's an example of how this file might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This file is automatically generated. Please do not modify the contents of this file.-->
<typeCache lastModified="04/01/2012 16:35:03" mvcVersionId="3cff62e5-ef21-4e58-897f-d0f1eafd3beb">
  <assembly name="Custom.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <module versionId="0bd9573a-7a89-4eab-b33d-cc92573fc2ba">
      <type>APPNAME.Controllers.BaseController</type>
    </module>
  </assembly>
  <assembly name="APPNAME.BusinessLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <module versionId="3fb0cce6-10dd-43d3-a44c-00046017b574">
      <type>APPNAME.BusinessLogic.Controllers.AssetsController</type>
      <type>APPNAME.BusinessLogic.Controllers.HomeController</type>
    </module>
  </assembly>
  <assembly name="MvcContrib, Version=2.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <module versionId="889dd733-c7a0-4ae6-8f50-934f417174ea">
      <type>MvcContrib.PortableAreas.EmbeddedResourceController</type>
      <type>MvcContrib.SubController</type>
    </module>
  </assembly>
</typeCache>
```

There's also the `MVC-AreaRegistrationTypeCache.xml` which is used to cache areas.

Comment: Thank for the answer Darin.I tried to look inside this folder but i was unable to find this file.

Comment: @NirajChoubey, are you running your application in Release mode? Did you set `<compilation debug="false" ...` in your web.config? This file is used only when you run in Release mode.