# Strange MVC Behaviour, AreaRegistrations firing twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am recently got done merging two MVC projects.  While debugging the new projects, pretty much all of a sudden, the single area in my project starts firing its **RegisterArea** method multiple times.  The stack trace tells me that **Application_Start** and **AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas** are only being fired once, but that internally, the area is being instantiated twice.

Other than the single default route, the AreaRegistration has nothing out of the ordinary.

I'm not sure where to start looking for the solution, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in, Start in Debugging mode, and check the stack trace each time the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Not to be rude, but I know to debug my application.  I've debugged it, refactored and the whole nine. I'm looking for what possible causes for an odd behaviour I've never encountered.

Comment: If you've done this, then surely you know where the second RegisterArea is being called from?

Comment: Yes, from AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas, which is framework code that automatically sniffs out classes of type AreaRegistration in the assembly.  The problem is that I only have one class of AreaRegistration but it's firing twice.

Comment: Clean your project manually (delete contents of bin), and use the Show All Files to check there are no files within the solution that are not a visible part of the project.  If you've been merging projects it's possible you've got something left over

Comment: Thank you, that's what it was.  I hadn't thought about the cache but it would make sense if there are multiple DLLs that AreaRegistration would pick them all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, MVC caches assemblies associated with an Area, and writes this data to a file.  You should be able to examine this file, and see why it think there should be two instances.

You can find more information on this file in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9032168/163495), but check the file at `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...\...\...\UserCache`.  Depending on how many projects you work with, this folder may be pretty busy, but I was able to find the sample project I just created by sorting by directory creation date.  I don't imagine deleting the contents of this directory would do much harm either.