# How to fix The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sitecore

I just deployed a new controller to my production environment.  For some reason, the controller does not get called.  All other controllers on the site work fine.  This is the only one that is failing. What I keep getting is the error:

> Error rendering controller BlogListing.GetIndex: Could not create
>   controller: 'BlogListing'. The controller for path '/' was not found
>   or does not implement IController

I've spent about 3 hours trying to troubleshoot this.  I have:

1. Added debug code into the controller to see if it is in fact being called. My debug statements does not get hit.
2. Verified the name of the controller is correct
3. I am using the default MVC routing.
4. Thinking that it might be a missing dependent dll, I copied all of the dlls from my production environment (where it is not working) to my local environment and it came right up
5. Checked file system permissions thinking that somehow it couldn't be read.
6. I did look at other posts regarding similar issues but none of those solutions worked or were not applicable

```
namespace Portal.Features.Blog.Controllers
{
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Portal.Foundation.Blog;
using portal.ct.gov.Models;
using Portal.Features.Blog.Models;
using portal.ct.gov.Business;


    public class BlogListingController : GlassController
    {
        public ActionResult GetIndex(string keyword = "", string page = "", string author = "")
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Blog Controller found", "portal.ct.gov");
            try
            {

                SitecoreContext scContext = new SitecoreContext();
                Item contextItem = scContext.GetCurrentItem<Item>();
                Item blogHome = null;
                //Get Blog Root

                if (contextItem != null)
                {
                    blogHome = contextItem.Axes.SelectSingleItem("ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename = 'Blog Section']");
                }
                var sKeyword = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Constants.QueryStrings.SearchKeyword]) ? HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Constants.QueryStrings.SearchKeyword] : string.Empty;
                var blogAuthor = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.QueryString["author"]) ? HttpContext.Request.QueryString["author"] : string.Empty;
                var blogCategory = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.QueryString["category"]) ? HttpContext.Request.QueryString["category"] : string.Empty;
                var blogPage = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.QueryString["page"]) ? HttpContext.Request.QueryString["page"] : "1";
                var model = GetBlogListing(blogHome, sKeyword, blogCategory, blogAuthor, Convert.ToInt32(blogPage));
                return View("/views/blog/BlogResultsMain.cshtml", model);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error processing bloglisting-->getINdex " + ex.Message, ex, "portal.ct.gov");
                return View("/views/blog/BlogResultsMain.cshtml");
            }
    }     

}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Please note that I am using Sitecore CMS.

Comment: I not see your action in controller, it's normal?

Comment: Sorry, I must have deleted it when I was trying to format the code for the post.  I edited my post and put the controller action in it

Comment: how you call your action, could you show it?

Comment: So that's where it get's hard because it's handled through the Sitecore CMS.  I I specify a rendering in sitecore and hit handles it from there.  I just found a quick work around.  I have my solution divided into multiple projects.  I added the controller to an existing project and it worked.  So something is wrong with that project. I assume it's some sort of dependency

Comment: Check you web.config https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/controller-constructor-injection-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Comment: It is worth checking the cached MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml file in folder c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\NAMEOFYOURAPP\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\UserCache\. If you can't find your controller there, remove the cached xml file and restart your website. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032087/mvc-controllertypecache-xml-in-mvc

Comment: @i123fr3 that was it!  Phrase your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth checking the cached `MVC-ControllerTypeCache.xml` file in folder `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\NAMEOFYOURAPP\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\UserCache\`.

If you can't find your controller there, remove the cached xml file and restart your website. More details you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032087/mvc-controllertypecache-xml-in-mvc)

Comment: That was it.  There was 2 servers where this was occurring on.  I've deployed controllers many times to these servers so I'm not sure why this particular controller was an issue but after removing that file, it started working.